# Effects of SHR on the higher byte of a register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

When shifting the bits of a higher byte, for example `AH`, will the ejected bit move directly to the `CF`, or will it first go into the lower byte, for example, `AL`?

Comment: This would have been trivial to test in a debugger if you weren't sure you were understanding [the documentation](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html) correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shift always shifts the bytes in the specified direction, *out* of the register. The last shifted bit is shifted into the carry flag (`CF`). This is all documented in the Intel manuals for the shift instructions ([this page](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html) contains a mirror of that documentation).

Therefore, doing `SHR ah, 1` will shift the ejected (least-significant) bit into the carry flag, and set the newly-emptied (most-significant) bit to 0.

*Only* the destination register is operated upon. The processor treats `AH` completely independently from `AX` (and thus, `AL`) for the purposes of this operation. While it is true that `AL` and `AH` give you a "view" on the lower and upper 8 bits of the full 16-bit `AX` register, if you specify one of those 8-bit registers as an operand to an instruction, the instruction will *only* operate on that partial register.

Perhaps you are confusing shift operations with [*rotate* operations](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_273.html)? These still treat the destination register independently of all other registers, but they basically implement a *circular* shift, such that the bits shifted out one end are rotated back into the other end of the value.

Comment: I think he's maybe unsure because of `ah:al` being "alias" for `ax`. From this kind of perspective your information about `ah` being treated separately is important. If it would be on the same physical bit inside CPU, it may look dangerous. But for OP: actually on modern CPUs the x86 registers get aliased (and renamed) to internal physical registers, keeping them separated until the programmer actually enforces some dependency, your code working only with `AH` and `AL` without touching `AX` is being done internally in two different regs, composing them into `AX` only upon its usage.

Comment: I thought about mentioning the aliasing and renaming of partial registers, but the question is tagged [intel-8088], so I'm assuming that is irrelevant here and would be needlessly confusing.